# XML parsing with optional element in regex

Tags: xml, regex

I have some xml that looks like:

```
<records>
  <Customer>
    <Reference>123</Reference>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>    
    <Address1>1, The street</Address1>
    <Address2>Upper Town Street</Address2>
    <Address3>Anytown</Address3>
    <Address4>County</Address4>
    <PostCode>POS TCD</PostCode>
  </Customer>
</records>
```

but for which Address2 is optional, so this is also valid:

```
<records>
  <Customer>
    <Reference>123</Reference>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>    
    <Address1>1, The street</Address1>
    <Address3>Anytown</Address3>
    <Address4>County</Address4>
    <PostCode>POS TCD</PostCode>
  </Customer>
</records>
```

(Note: this is a cut down xml snippet)

I have the following regex that matches correctly when Address2 is specified:

```
<Reference>(?<Reference>.*)</Reference>[\w|\W]*<Name>(?<Name>.*)</Name>[\w|\W]*<Address1>(?<Address1>.*)</Address1>[\w|\W]*<Address2>(?<Address2>.*)</Address2>
```

It doesn't work for the case when Address2 isn't specified. 
The closest I've got is the following :

```
<Reference>(?<Reference>.*)</Reference>[\w|\W]*<Name>(?<Name>.*)</Name>[\w|\W]*<Address1>(?<Address1>.*)</Address1>[\w|\W]*(<Address2>(?<Address2>.*)</Address2>)?
```

which matches and populates Reference, Name and Address1 for both xml snippets, but which leaves Address2 blank in both cases rather than having a value of Upper Town Street for Address 2 for the first snippet.

Aside: I know that using an xml parser would be probably easier but the xml isn't clean and this was supposed to be a quick and easy solution(!). I also know that I can break this down into a set of regexs to resolve, but this has now become a bit of an intellectual challenge. And I'd love to have a solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty answer:

```
<Reference>(?<Reference>.*)</Reference>[\w\W]*?<Name>(?<Name>.*)</Name>[\w\W]*?<Address1>(?<Address1>.*)</Address1>[\w\W]*?(<Address2>(?<Address2>.*)</Address2>)?
```

First, I removed the `|`; it wasn't harming anything, but it was unnecessary.  `[\w\W]` already means *a word character, or a character that's **not** a word character*.  Like most other metacharacters, `|` loses its special meaning inside a character class, and just matches itself.

But the main point was changing the `*` to `*?`, making it non-greedy.  Each `[\w\W]*` initially gobbles up the whole rest of the text, then backtracks so it can match the next required part (e.g., `<Name>(?<Name>.*)</Name>`).  But the `Address2` part is *not* required, so the regex engine doesn't bother backtracking to take it in.

Making the quantifier non-greedy reverses the priorities: before it gobbles up the next character, it first tries to match the *next* part of the regex.  That ensures that the `Address2` line gets matched if present, even though it's optional.

But if your XML is really formatted the way you showed it, all there is between the elements is whitespace.  I would just use `\s*`, and not have to worry about it matching too much or too little.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Good point on the | character, thanks for picking that up. And thanks for the well-explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), **fix your broken [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)** and use your mind on a most interesting problem =)

[regex](/questions/tagged/regex) are not the right tool to parse a [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) file. Parsing [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) in 2013 is a resolved problem, don't try to re-invent the wheel.

Like you already said, use an *XML parser*. Add your language in your original POST if you want me to give you some of these.

The best I know to parse [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) & [html](/questions/tagged/html) is [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

---

See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: as I said in the post, I know that using an XML parser would be easier and is the right way to solve it, but this is now an intellectual challenge that I'd like to fix via a regex.